# Powershell: Count lines, edit and save

Tags: powershell

it is my first time using powershell, I am aiming to create a ps1 script that counts the lines in a csv file(or pipe separated), and then ads a new line at the end.

So far I know how to get a count of the lines (excluding header)

```
(Import-Csv C:\Users\xx\Documents\test.csv).count
27575 <--result
```

This is the ps1 file script i created. (not sure if it works)

```
#count lines
$fileLocation = "C:\Users\xx\Documents\test.csv"
$countRecords = (Import-Csv $fileLocation).count
```

This is a sample of the file:

```
id|number
1|12345
2|123456
3|1234565
4|123456
5|123456
```

How it is supposed to look

```
id|number
1|12345
2|123456
3|1234565
4|123456
5|123456
T|5
```

Where T is the trailer record and 5 the number of record counts or lines excluding the header.

To summarize, I need to count the records(excluding header) add a new line to the very bottom with the total count (T|$totalCount) and save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'v got it, you just need to create the new line and append it tou your file. You can try :

```
(Import-Csv C:\temp\t.csv -Delimiter '|').count | %{$a="T|$_";$a} | Add-Content C:\temp\t.csv
```

Comment: Am I the only one that cringes at the idea of doing an import-csv on 27K rows, just to get a line count?

Comment: This worked, could you please explain how this bit works `%{$a="T|$_";$a}`  how is the count being assigned to "$_;$a" thanks works good!

Comment: The % is an alias of `foreach-object` CmdLet (here $_ will receive only one value -> the count). `$a` will be the new line that I put back to the pipe to append to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to append the record count to the file without modifying anything else I'd probably do something like this:

```
$csv = "C:\Users\xx\Documents\test.csv"

Select-String '^' $csv | % { $cnt = $_.LineNumber }
"T|$($cnt-1)" | Out-File $csv -Append
```

Note that this appends the totals to the last line of the file. If your CSV doesn't end with a trailing newline you'll get this result:

```
id|number
1|12345
2|123456
3|1234565
4|123456
5|123456T|5
```

rather than this:

```
id|number
1|12345
2|123456
3|1234565
4|123456
5|123456
T|5
```

You could insert the missing newline by changing `"T|$($cnt-1)"` to `` "`r`nT|$($cnt-1)" ``, but then you'd get a spurious empty line when the CSV does end with a trailing newline.

A better approach would be to check if the ends with a line feed (ASCII character 10) and modify the appended string accordingly:

```
if ( [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($csv)[-1] -eq 10 ) {
  "T|$($cnt-1)" | Out-File $csv -Append
} else {
  "`r`nT|$($cnt-1)" | Out-File $csv -Append
}
```